# silverlight 4 treeview silently throws Binding Errors

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, treeview, treeviewitem

So I have a silverlight treeview control bound to the type below, I set the `DataContext` of my page to an instance of my ViewModel which has a `Divisions` property that is a List of `RmDivision` objects.

```
public class RmDivision
    {
        public RmDivision()
        {
            SubDivisions = new ObservableCollection<RmDivision>();
        }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<RmDivision> SubDivisions { get; set; }
    }
```

And then its bound like this:

```
 <sdk:TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="treeBranches" 
                          ItemsSource="{ Binding Divisions }"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedValuePath="Division" Grid.Row="0" SelectedItemChanged="treeBranches_SelectedItemChanged">
                <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding SubDivisions}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Type}" />
                    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </sdk:TreeView>
```

Now, I get no exceptions, everytime I **click** a treeeview item, only in my **output window** I see:

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Division' property not found on 'xxx.Base.RmDivision' 'xxx.Base.RmDivision' (HashCode=35753827). BindingExpression: Path='Division' DataItem='xxx.Base.RmDivision' (HashCode=35753827); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'System.Object')..

I'm kinda a newbie here and don't really know what is going on, the only way I know it is the treeview is because thats the only control that has to do anything with a `Division` property, is it the `SelectedValuePath`, I want the SelectedItem to be an instance of RmDivision and current it works like this.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division is not a property of RmDivision.  So every time you select a treeviewitem it will try to lookup the property and it can't find it.

Comment: +1 thx..hmm but how else would I bind it, the `Divisions` property is part of the Pages ViewModel? The app loads the data and behaves perfectly fine actually, but I do want the error gone.

Comment: Just remove the SelectedValuePath.  if this property is empty, it will take the itemvalue of your list.

Comment: lol thanks! worked like a charm. So you're saying by default, `SelectedValuePath` is just the object it is assigned? right?

Comment: Yes, it will result in an empty property path wich refers to the entity itself.